# How do I suppress duplicate lines in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, user-input, readline

I am making a **Kahoot Bot** and I want it to have a feature where I can have the user to choose an answer. I am using **readline** to **grab user input** (example code of what I am doing):

```js
var rl = require("readline").createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Type in your answer!\n', (answer) => {
     console.log(answer)
})
```

but each player (bot) is **separated** and is **not** like in 1 cluster. (Cluster as in each bot has the same mind as another one, a.k.a it doesn't spam my console.) I've tried using emitters but I have no idea how to use EventEmitter so I stopped using them.
So if I try to do the above code (with 100+ bots), I end up getting my whole console **spammed** with duplicate characters and lines. How can I hide this?

Comment: What do mean by a cluster?  And which part of the code is being duplicated? The callback where you are logging the answer? Why not simply extract it into a seperate function?

Comment: What I mean by a cluster is like each bot has the same mind as another one. So if it's not a cluster, it would spam my console but if it was a cluster it wouldn't spam my console. I've tried using emitters before but I don't know how to set it up. Sorry if it isn't clear its my first time.

Comment: okay i think the issue is that you want to ask only `one` question at a given time even though you have multiple users, that right?

Comment: Correct, that is what I was going for.

Comment: Okay maybe it was just me but I think the question can still be reworded.

Comment: Yeah I agree, i was very unclear.

Comment: As for the solution, I believe you want a synchronous version of readline where the programs waits for user input before moving to next line of code.

Comment: Ah, so like readline-sync? But how would that stop all the spam though? It would still run all the multiple lines but after each question

Comment: yes well if your bot is going to ask questions, they'll be printed in the console. Or you'll have to find some other way of asking the questions

Comment: Okay thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, made a variable and a `if` statement so if 1 bot does it (since the bots are delayed) the variable turns true and so if another bot does it, it goes to a `else` statement instead.